# Block camera roll while following path

Tags: camera, constraints, path, axis

I'm trying to make the camera do a kind of tracking shot in 3D space. So I created a bezier curve, added a Follow path constraint to the camera, and selected the curve.

Then, since I want the orientation of the camera to change, I checked Follow Curve, and this is fine.

Except, I'd like only the pan and the tilt of the camera to be affected by the path, not the roll. Since the curve is not horizontal, the roll is affected too.

is it possible to block the camera roll? What's the least difficult way to do it in Bender?

I already tried to use an additional Limit Rotation constraint, and even make an empty follow the path and parent camera to empty, but it didn't seem to work. Maybe it's a matter of global vs local axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a first shot, if you have used a 'Follow Path' constraint,  -Z tracking, Y up, then ensuring the Tilt of all the curve's control points is set to 0, and setting the'Twist Method' to 'Z up' in the curve's Data tab > Shape panel *should* be enough.